# "Install alongside Windows 10" not showing in installer 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm new in Linux world so for the first time I downloaded ubuntu 17.10.1 and booted on my flash drive and there was an option "Install alongside Windows 10" so I chose that and installed it on my new partition. 
But I saw 18.04 and wanted fresh install so I deleted 17.10 partition and booted 18.04 image but I can't see "Install alongside Windows 10" option and it's completely gone. 
I even reinstalled my windows but it didn't change anything.
I tried "Something Else" option but I didn't have any idea how to install ubuntu manually, but in partition tools I saw my windows partition but there wasn't any windows label on it.
So any idea how can I get that option back?

Comment: Windows normal shutdown is actually hibernation. And Updates turn the fast start up back on. Make sure it is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Your disk may be using dos partitioning, limited to 4 primary partitions, if Windows is in legacy mode.  Do you have unallocated free space on the disk and only 3 or fewer Windows partitions?

Comment: @oldfred I tried to disable fast boot, but it didn't help still can't see windows 10 on installer

Comment: @ubfan1 i got 3 partition, 1 primary for windows and 1 extended partition and another unlocatable for linux

Comment: Is this a newer system? And then Windows would have been UEFI boot. But if you booted installer in BIOS boot mode, it will install in BIOS boot mode. And Windows does not correctly convert a gpt partitioned drive to MBR(msdos) and you have to remove the backup gpt partition table. MBR has no backup. Post this from terminal in Ubuntu live installer:  `sudo fdisk -lu` Copy  in question above and preserve formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extended partition on your disk means it's using dos partitioning, so Windows is in legacy mode.  The machine settings control how the Ubuntu install media boots, since it has both boot mechanisms, check that UEFI is turned off or is not the preferred boot mechanism.  Booting the install media in UEFI mode will not see Windows in legacy mode.  Ubuntu doesn't need  a primary partition to boot, a logical partition within the extended partition is fine.  If you have unallocated space (not in a logical partition) in your extended partition, Ubuntu may be installed there.

Comment: thanks mate it worked. My mistake was I was booting ubuntu in UEFI mode.